# How to use Visual Studio 2017 Codegen ClangC2 from command line?

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017, build-tools

I'm trying to build a simple 'empty main' application with the Clang/C2 compiler from the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools (on an x64 system). I have started the `...\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` shell as suggested, but realized that it does not add the path to the clang.exe compiler, so `clang` was not available. Added the path manually (the x64 hosted version), so `clang` can be invoked, too.

Trying to build the simplest possible program with a simple empty main function body results in the following error:

```
clang hello.cc -o hello.exe
error: failed to load c2 (file not found)
```

c2.dll is the MS linker that clang supposed to pull in for linking, however it seems it cannot find it.

I have tried to build the same program from the IDE itself and it is obviously successful as the IDE separately calls the compiler and than the linker (i.e. it does not rely on the compiler to call the linker, but instead calls link.exe directly)

***Does anybody know how to get the clang/c2 compiler into a working shape?*** (Previously I was able to do the same with Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Clang is too stupid to find **link.exe** in Windows, despite it being in the `PATH`.

The solution is creating symbolic links to **link.exe** next to the **clang.exe** executable, by using the `MKLINK` command:

```
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\ClangC2\14.10.25903\bin\HostX64"
mklink link.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe"

cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\ClangC2\14.10.25903\bin\HostX86"
mklink link.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe"
```

The above solution is hackish, may require Administrator privileges, and assumes that the crosslinkers are compatible with the native ones.

Comment: Indeed clang/c2 does not use the path to locate Link.exe which is strange. I have tracked this down also using a process monitor. It is possible also to copy the link.exe into the current directory, but that is even more hackish. Thanks for the tip.